# Yii2 model search between query

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-model

I Want to impliment below mysql query in yii2 model search()

```
SELECT * FROM `parking_availability` WHERE  ('09:00' BETWEEN `time_start` AND `time_end` ) AND 
 ( '11:00' BETWEEN `time_start` AND `time_end` )
```

I have applied like this

```
 $query->andFilterWhere([$this->arrivaltime,'between','time_star', 'time_end'])
->andFilterWhere([$this->departuretime,'between','time_star', 'time_end']);
```

But its showing error  **Operator '09:00' requires two operands.**

Please help me , Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You were in the right direction in your attempts, but you got the parameters in the wrong order. The first has to be the `'between'` operator:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['between', $this->arrivaltime, 'time_start', 'time_end'])
->andFilterWhere(['between', $this->departuretime, 'time_start', 'time_end']);
```

Comment: what is 'time_start', 'time_end' here and from where it is coming

Comment: I assumed they were columns in his `parking_availability ` table

Comment: will you please visit this  question of mine.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708512/how-to-filter-date-field-in-yii2