# yii2 find values between two timestamps

Tags: php, yii2

What am trying is to query orders created between two dates

so i have

```
$maxdate = ; //timestamp value
$mindate = ; //timestamp value   


$orders = Orders::find()->where(["created_at" ..]) //stuck hre
```

IN normal words would be

```
find where created_at is between $maxdate and $mindate
```

How do i go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 model search between query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318711/yii2-model-search-between-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve your goal by this

```
$orders = Orders::find()->where(["between", "created_at", $mindate, $maxdate])
```

[This is the fully reference about building various of Queries](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#operator-format)