# How to filter date field in yii2

Tags: date, yii2

I want to filter Date column like 3 months ago, 6 months ago, 1 year ago.
I have created a dropdown in search field of gridview as given below.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'modified',
    'value'     => 'name',
    'filter'    => array("ID1" => "Before Three months",
                         "ID2" => "Before six months",
                         "ID"  => "Before Twelve months",),
],
```

and in modelsearch I want to search like...

```
if (($this->modified) == "ID1"){
    $query->andFilterWhere(['between', $this->modified, 'today', '3monthsago']);
}
```

but I can't understand what should be there in place of today 3monthsago ?
how to calculate and pass this variables in query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your modelsearch

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
if (($this->modified)=="ID1"){
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-3 months'));
    $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'contacts.modified', $today, $endDate]);
}elseif (($this->modified)=="ID2") {
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-6 months'));
    $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'contacts.modified', $today, $endDate]);
}elseif (($this->modified)=="ID") {
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-12 months'));
    $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'contacts.modified', $today, $endDate]);
}
```

Comment: Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'modified' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts` LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `contacts`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `contacts`.`country` = `countries`.`country_code` WHERE (`modified`='ID2') AND (`ID2` BETWEEN '2017-12-08 06:10:54' AND '08/06/2017')

Comment: Same error not possible. You can try it by clear your yii2 cache @Goli

Comment: remove all the files from folder `YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/runtime/cache` @Goli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160768/discussion-between-naim-malek-and-goli).

Comment: see the chat. I have resolved the error . now neither showing error nor the result.what should be the mistake?

Comment: In which format exactly are you storing `modified`?

Comment: @NaimMalek actually simple search/filter is also not working....means ...->andFilterWhere(['like', 'modified', $this->modified]).....this code is not working.. giving error...Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'modified' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts` LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `contacts`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `contacts`.`country` = `countries`.`country_code` WHERE (`modified`='2017') AND (`modified` LIKE '%2017%')

Comment: do you any idea about it?? didnt  found anythis about it